# Converting to DateTime from Text Value

Tags: datetime, ssis, casting, type-conversion, formatdatetime

I have a bunch of extracts that I receive from a vendor. I built SSIS packages to load the data to my server and when everything loads it just as nvarchar into a staging table and then I will convert what values need to be converted using T-SQL before they are merged into the final table.

I am having trouble getting the date/time values that are stored as text to convert to true datetime.

I am simply just working with a select statement trying to determine the best way to do the conversion at this point and once I have that working I can get it all back into my SSIS package.

```
Examples of Data:

7/1/2021   1224,
7/1/2021   1328,
7/1/2021   1438,
7/1/2021   1447,
```

I would like to be able to make it look something like this:
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

I've tried this amongst other cast and format and convert options but bottom line is with everything I get the same error:

```
convert(datetime, convert(varchar(30), Discharge_Date_Time), 108)
```

**Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.**

Any ideas?? I have been stuck on this all day and I have to do it for a lot more columns that I am bringing in from this vendor.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
let date = new Date('7/1/2021');
```

Answer (score 0):

CAST(STUFF([your date column], 12, 0, ':') AS datetime)

Comment: I still get the same error unfortunately.

Comment: CAST(STUFF(REPLACE([Discharge_Date_Time], '  ', ' '), 12, 1, ':') AS DATETIME)          as you have 2 spaces in between